# Flutter:How can I get image from video,

Tags: flutter

I want create slider from video images. In my project I am using video_player package.Can I get images from video?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

See if that package helps . It says it can capture full screen as well as individual widgets.

Comment: I want create video trimmer, but if I using this package I can't show trimmer while video not finished